# Unity, to what object should I attach my game engine script

Tags: unity-game-engine

Me and my friend are building a simple idle game as our first project in unity.
We got to the point at which we build a script that handles all calculations, and communicates with each `GameObject` the player sees.

Now, to what should we attach this script?

We would rather not use a `GameObject` because:

1) The `GameObject` would be an overkill

2) The `GameObject` lies in the space where all of my "physical" objects exist (That would be useless since the script does not have to "exist somewhere")

First time posting in stackoverflow, if I made any mistake please tell me ^^

Comment: Perhaps this question should be in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It's fine here since it relates to programming. There are plenty of Unity3D questions on both sites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convention says to put it on the main camera or an empty `GameObject`.

If you really don't want to do either of those, you could make your class static.

If your class inherits from `MonoBehaviour` you have to attach it to a `GameObject`. If you want to attach it to a `GameObject` it has to inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

If you want to better understand the Unity way, I advise you to read up on Entity-Component Systems:

`GameObject` are Entities

`MonoBehaviour` are Components

Services and managers generally get implemented as Components in Unity which then get attach to the main camera or to empty `GameObject`s named after them.

Comment: Thank you very much ^^
All of those information are really useful!
I believe we will simply attach the scrip to the camera ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can create a usual singleton class, and "Game Initializer" monobehaviour, that will initialize all your singletone managers, fabrics, etc...

Just add this monobehaviour to every scene in empty gameobject with a code like that:

```
if(GameManager.instance == null)
   new GameManager();
```

Or in case of scriptableObjects,

```
if(GameManager.instance == null)
   gameManager.init()
```

Also, a good desicion is to use Entity System pattern, here is frameworks for unity (Unity-Ash, Entitas, etc)

Comment: What's the point of having a singleton if you're going to attach the script to an empty gameobject anyway? It doesn't make sense

Comment: When you switch scenes, gameobject will be recreated with all it's monobehaviours. Even if you use DontDestroyOnLoad(), it's a bit difficult to get all your managers have only one instance, and save their states, when they are monobehaviours.

Also, new monobehaviours can take time to load/GC, wasting cpu time.

Comment: It's not difficult to use `DontDestroyOnLoad()` and I've had no problems ensuring I only have one instance of my managers through using it. You haven't answered my previous concern though, your answer seems to suggest having singleton that is also a `MonoBehaviour` that is attached to a gameobject.

Comment: If you want to launch your game from any scene in editor, DontDestroyOnLoad() is not enough. You should also disable awake()  calls for all your "one instance monobehaviours"
It's much easier to disable it once.
Also, Monobehaviours add many fields to autocomplete, making self not handy to use as managers.

Comment: Best way i know to create managers is:  
1) One monobehaviour initializer 
2) Managers, extended from ScriptableObject class, with static link to self, public fields (filled with prefabs etc), and methods you need.